# Unable to upload file using angular JS and Spring controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am not understanding url: '/api/fileupload/',
$scope.uploadFiles = function () {

```
            var request = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/api/fileupload/',
                data: formdata,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': undefined
                }
            };

            // SEND THE FILES.
            $http(request)
                .success(function (d) {
                    alert(d);
                })
                .error(function () {
                });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used a while ago to upload xlm files using angular:

```
this.uploadFile = function($file) {
        // $http() returns a $promise that we can add handlers with .then()
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: restUrl + "/rest/data/upload",
            data: $file,
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
```

Also make sure you are accepting `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA` on your server

Comment: I am not understood this  url: restUrl + "/rest/data/upload",  where is d file v r sending in my code

Comment: this is just an example i got out of my own code. In your case it should be '/api/fileupload/'